# How to use a variable defined in another function?

Tags: php, fat-free-framework

Using Fat Free Framework I have a function in the user controller which defines the variable foo:

```
public function home(){
$foo = "hello";
}
```

I have another function in which id like to be able to access the variable foo,

```
public function house(){
$this->f3->set('bar', $foo);
}
```

How would I go about doing tihs?

Comment: its impossible, you cannot access variable inside other function

Comment: @Lashane ah really, any other way around this or other routes to take?

Comment: Its hard to say without knowing what you actually want to achieve

Comment: @Lashane I have a variable defined in one function, I want it to appear in the header of every page. It works on the pages that are using the function that the variable is defined in. But pages that aren't linked to that function at all cannot find the variable. So.. :(

Comment: `It works on the pages that are using the function that the variable is defined in` - probably you should start with this approach

Comment: @Gee, you're looking for help on how to start working with F3. https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/f3-framework is the right place for your questions.

Answer (score 0):

You can access variable, classes objects if you used $f3->set() and $f3->get() methods.

Initialize the variable in your first function.

```
function firstFunc(){
 $f3=\Base::instance();
 $f3->set('bookName','Time Travelling');
}
```

And access variable in second function this way:

```
function secondFunc(){
 $f3=\Base::instance();
 $bookName = $f3->get('bookName');
 echo $bookName;

 $f3->set('bookName', 'Software Strategies';

}
```